# Can i disable fullPage.js if depending on div size?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, fullpage.js

Sorry if this is stupid question, but i'm not the greatest coder alive (actually i design websites for a living).

My question is: **Can i disable fullPage.js depending on a div size?**

I've been trying to look this up, but with no luck. I found this, but i don't think i know how to tweak it right, or if it's even possible:

```
    if(.scrollable.width < 480) { 
       $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            autoScrolling: false,
            fitToSection: false
    }} else {
       $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            autoScrolling: true,
            fitToSection: true
    }}

.scrollable = div starting at 0vw and expanding to 50vw.
```

**I want the scroll from fullPage.js to stop when this div is bigger than 1vw**.

Is this possible? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the responsive options provided by fullPage.js, such as `responsiveWidth` and `responsiveHeight`. You can find all about those options in the [fullpage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). And you can find [examples online](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html).

Example of usage:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    responsiveWidth: 900,
    responsiveHeight: 600
});
```

Additionally you can make use of the `fp-auto-height-responsive` class as [in this example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/WZmMgZ), to allow sections bigger than the viewport once in responsive mode.

Also, you can make use of the [Responsive Slides extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/) if you want to convert horizontal slides to vertical sections when reaching the responsive point.